# Empty columns using pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, nan

see I'm doing a simple merge between two data frames, the one I'm working with is called BD, and has about 50 columns, the other data frame is called PROD and has only three columns productID, productDesc, ponderation, the first two columns obviously contain string values and the last one float values, the BD data frame also contains the column productID. My problem is that when I try to add the ponderation column to BD through

```
BD = BD.merge(PROD[['productID', 'ponderation']], on = 'productID', how = 'left')
```

The column ponderation is added but all values are NaN (I forgot to mention BD's length is 84300).

I don't know what the problem may be, I think the code is correct and I have tried a few things like to merge the complete data frame or just one column and so, but I get the same output, the data types are the same so I'm confused on what I could be doing wrong therefore I'm asking for some help,

Thaaaaaaaanks

Comment: are you sure BD and PROD have any common productIDs? also, make sure there is no whitespaces, as they can also mess the matches up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use `BD = BD.merge(PROD[['productID', 'ponderation']].set_index('productID'), on = 'productID', how = 'left')`

The `set_index` seems necessary